# Getting an error while bundle install in rails core project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I forked and cloned the rails project on my machine. I am doing `bundle install` and it throws me this...

`Updating git://github.com/rails/arel.git
Updating git://github.com/brynary/rack-test.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/jquery-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/coffee-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/voloko/sdoc.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (~> 2.1.4) ruby' in git://github.com/rails/jquery-rails.git (at master).
Source contains 'jquery-rails' at: 2.2.1`

What is happening here ? I've got no clue.

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Answer (score 0):

> "Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (~> 2.1.4)".

Looks like it doesn't find "jquery-rails" or the specific version in your Gemfile.

You will have to install jquery-rails (~> 2.1.4) or if you have it then comment out the version portion in your Gemfile

You can use following to see if you have installed
    gem list --local | grep -i jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can run `gem list` to see if you have a conflicting version in your `rvm gemset`. The other thing is to drop the version number and let bundler resolve the dependency itself. Just include `gem 'jquery-rails'`. When weird things like this happen to me its usually something with the `rvm gemset` I'm overlooking